# SQL Server 2016 Report Builder not showing data

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-2016, reportbuilder

The Database I am using is Microsoft SQL Server 2016 and its on a different machine. 
I am using SQL Server 2016 Report Builder (14.0.344.82).

- I create a new report.
- Then I create a Data Source.
- Then I create a Dataset of "Text" Query type, the query I wrote has
  no parameters and returns a result set of 2 columns.
- Then I create a table and link its columns with the fields of
  dataset.

Now I run the report inside Report Builder. I can see through the SQL Profiler that the concerned query is executed. But I dont see the data in the Report Builder. How come? I ran the concerned query in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio and it return 8 rows. So I should have seen 8 rows in Report Builder. But I am not seeing a single row.

- I right-click the dataset to open right-click menu, then click on "Query..." menu option to open “Query Designer” dialog box; then I Run Query in there and I can see 8 rows are retrieved. So the dataset is fine.
- I dont have any filters for the dataset.

Thanks

Comment: Check the mapping whether it is correct or not?

Comment: If you copy the same dataset to a new one, can it return anything? i.e is the dataset the problem (corrupted or something). Otherwise it's behaving counter to how it should, I think.

Comment: When you run the report, do you see the column headers? Also have you checked the tablix properties to confirm that it is referencing the dataset?